# Postgresql fails authentification despite correct password

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to run my application on WildFly and once trying to get some data from a postgresql database, I get an error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myuser".

This is a new user, so the password I provided in properties for my DriverManageris definitely correct, I can easily use it when I log into my database via terminal.

I've tried to play with pg_hba.conf and tried md5/peer and trust options, however, it didn't work. What is the way my connection can get authorized properly?

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust
local   all             myuser                                 trust
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             postgres                                     trust
local   all             myuser                                       trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

Java code:

```java
Connection connection; 
Properties props = new Properties(); 
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db"; 
props.setProperty("user","myuser"); 
props.setProperty("password","password"); 
try { 
   Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); 
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
}
```

Full error thread:

```
13:28:51,267 SEVERE [org.postgresql.Driver] (default task-3) Connection error: : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myuser"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:438)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:222)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at servlets.EmployeeServlet.getEmployees(EmployeeServlet.java:61)
    at servlets.EmployeeServlet.doGet(EmployeeServlet.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The granted accesses for "myuser" are below

```
Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of | Description 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------
 adminuser | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}        | 
 myuser    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}        | 
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}        |
```

Comment: Can you please add full stacktrace ?

Comment: what's your connect string?

Comment: Are you sure you've granted required privileges on your DB to user "myuser"?

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko added to the question

Comment: @KedarJoshi added to the question

Comment: @VaoTsun String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db";

Comment: hm - I dont see myuser in connect string... and what terminal command successfully connects?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I do connect via the following implementation:
 `Connection connection;
           Properties props = new Properties();
           String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db";
           props.setProperty("user","myuser");
           props.setProperty("password","password");
  try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);`

Comment: and if I open a terminal and log into my_db via myuser, I provide my password and it works fine, i am logged in

Comment: What is result of `SELECT * FROM has_database_privilege('myuser', 'my_db', 'connect');` ?

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko
`has_database_privilege 
------------------------
 t
(1 row)`

Comment: It looks more like the candidate to the https://dba.stackexchange.com/ instead SO, but ok its already moving forward over there

Comment: "*password authentication failed for user*" always means you supplied the wrong password. I'm inclined to believe Postgres more than your statement that you are passing the correct password.